# Como somar valores de JSpinners?

Tags: java, swing, conversão-de-tipo

Quero fazer um simples programa onde o usuário põe um numero num `JSpinner` e, ao clicar num botão, aparecerá em outro `JSpinner`, o valor do primeiro somado por 2.
Porém, não consigo fazer a soma entre o valor indicado no `JSpinner` e 2, pois o valor do `JSpinner` não é considerado `int`. Como faço?

Aqui está uma amostra do codigo:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Object w = jSpinner2.getValue();
    jSpinner1.setValue(w+2); //Aqui acontece o erro  

    //JSpinner1 é o valor final.
    //JSpi nner2 é o valor indicado pelo usuario.
}
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um parse para int?

Comment: Desculpe sou novo em java, poderia-me explicar o que é um parse int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer o cast para `Integer` antes de somar o valor no novo Spinner:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int w = (Integer)jSpinner2.getValue();//cast de object para int
    jSpinner1.setValue(w+2);  

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Já funcionou